# Can Array modifier work in global coordinates?

Tags: modifiers

[image]

These two black marked object are joint together, I want them to multiple with array modifier in red axes, but unfortunately array modifier copies the object in blue axes. How can achieve this?

Comment: Could you describe better what you want to achieve?

Comment: Select the object, Ctrl+A (Apply rotation)?